# Text (drawn using texture and effect) is shown on open-source driver but not NVidia blob

Tags: linux, opengl

I have a code that uses textures and effects (I suppose those are shaders) to draw text. This works fine under nouveau driver, under virtualbox (software driver I suppose), but does not work under NVidia blob. The rest of the scene (actually a kind of 2D chart being exported) is drawn fine.

The text is drawn like this:
glActiveTexture
glBindTexture
glDrawElements

But this is only for info, my real question is how do I debug this? I run under Ubuntu 12.04. Doing glGetError after each call is too much (there's a lot of calls as it's a big project and I don't know what parts are the cause), and I don't even know if it will help.

UPDATE: ok gDebugger was very useful. I see textures and they seem to be flipped (mirrored) both vertically and horizontally when run under nvidia blob. I see two calls in code for glTexParameteri(...GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S/T) but yet to find out if nouveau doesn't mirror textures and if that's the cause.
UPDATE2: no, in nouveau they are also mirrored.

Comment: What do you precisely want to debug?

Comment: Why part of scene is drawn using one driver and not drawn using another driver on same linux machine.

Comment: Probably because one of the drivers doesn't support the OpenGL version needed.

Comment: I used gDebugger and it shows no error (I set break on errors). I doubt that native nvidia proprietary driver supports less than software virtualbox rendering. But even if so, the question is then how do I detect what is not supported?

Comment: So to clarify, your `glDrawElements` doesn't draw anything? Can you double check it's not just drawing black/same as background? Perhaps the texture isn't being referenced (are you using shaders)? Is depth testing/backface culling/blending enabled by default in one driver and not another? If `glDrawElements` is indeed not drawing anything, what makes it different to your other draw calls that do work?

Comment: You have not given sufficient information to answer this question. Off the top of my head, you may be using a core context on the NV implementation and attempting to use arrays stored in client memory (as opposed to a VBO). This will not generate an error that `glGetError (...)` will catch, but I am pretty sure gDEBugger is smart enough to detect this situation.

Comment: For now the only difference I've found (using gDebugger I raw-exported all buffers and compared) is that nvidia reuses VBO numbers after glDeleteBuffers, i.e. if I delete VBO #3 then next glGenBuffer will have also #3, while with nouveau it will always increase the number. I suspect that this may interfere with internal caching/hashing of buffers, yet to confirm.